# Can I send http request to IP address and get response in shell script. For example:1.1.1.1/api/1.do?1=1

Tags: shell, curl

Can I send http request to IP address and get response in shell script. For example:1.1.1.1/api/1.do?1=1
When I try to use curl 1.1.1.1/api/1.do?1=1 or curl http://1.1.1.1/api/1.do?1=1 it show nothing. This is in shell script of website. when I curl other site it work well.
However, I use curl in windows commandline it work well.

Answer (score 0):

curl.bat:

```
CMD /k curl %1
```

From command line in CMD.

```
C:>\apps>curl http://127.0.0.1/apps/curltest.php?1=1
```

That works. Does a Windows batch file work for you?